# How to inherit template constructor that will not work with base class instances?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have **many** derived classes from base. Those classes must inherit constructor from base, but that constructor should only work with derived or base class instances.

Base class example:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
struct bar
{ 
  bar() = default;

  template<typename _Bar_or_Derived>
  bar(const _Bar_or_Derived &); // must accept any bar or its derived classes
};
```

Derived classes example:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo : public bar<T, U>
{ 
  using bar<T, U>::bar; 

 // must inherit something like foo(const Foo_or_Bar&)
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct not_foo : public bar<T, U>
{ 
  using bar<T, U>::bar; 

 // must inherit something like not_foo(const NotFoo_or_Bar&)
};
```

How to do such a thing?

Comment: Inheritance appears to be an all-or-nothing proposition. Either you inherit a constructor, or don't inherit a constructor. If the constructor is a template, you either inherit the template, or you don't inherit a template. If you don't mind an explicit wrapper, you can manually declare a derived class constructor with variadic parameters that forwards its parameters to the instantiated template constructor from the base class. That's probably the most that can be done here.

Comment: But that will allow base class to be constructed with derived, won't it? Could you provide some example code?

Comment: Of course, because that's how C++ works, unless the derived class privately-inherits the base class.

Comment: Ok, but if I change `bar<_U, _T>` to `typename _Bar` and SFINAE check?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you feel the need to prevent the constructor from accepting an instance of derived class? What is the ultimate problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you want some kind of CRTP? to define `bar(const foo<_T, _U>&)`?

Comment: I believe using an inherited copy constructor like this would leave any `foo`-specific fields not copied. Are you sure you want this? You could just leave the implicitly defined copy constructor, which should call the base copy constructor.

Comment: I create `chrono::duration` like classes with base of abstract unit class. That's why only `base<->derived` conversion must be possible. It makes no sense to convert `derived_1<->derived_2` as makes no sense to convert `hours to km`

Comment: `derived1<->base<->derived2` though...

Comment: `derived1<->base<->derived2` is ok. It won't happen accidentally at least. And it makes some sense to converrt `km<->unit<->hour`

Comment: *"// must inherit something like foo(const foo<_T, _U> &)"* that seems you want `foo1 <-> foo2` which is the derived class.

Comment: Yeah, but that is the instance of `foo<...>`. Only instances of `not_foo<...>` must not work

Comment: Why do you want to inherit constructors (`base` has not constructor taking `foo`, and the one taking `base` is problematic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211960/discussion-between-hououin-kyouma-and-jarod42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) instead of common base class to avoid to duplicate code:

```
template <typename > struct Bar;
template <template <typename, typename> class C, typename T1, typename T2>
struct Bar<C<T1, T2>>
{
     Bar(const Bar&) {/*..*/}

     template <typename U1, U2>
     Bar(const Bar<C<U1, U2>>&) {/*..*/}

     template <typename U1, U2>
     Bar(const C<U1, U2>&) {/*..*/}
};
// Maybe you just need template <template <typename, typename> class C> struct Bar{};
// instead, as T1, T2 seems not used

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo : public bar<foo>
{ 
    using bar<foo>::bar;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct not_foo : public bar<not_foo>
{ 
  using bar<not_foo>::bar;
};
```